# Error downloading MODIS images using runGdal

Tags: r, gdal

everyone~

I tried in vain in R to download MODIS images of my places of interest, however, I always get the same error. Can any one help me out?

Thanks in advance~

Here is the code:

```
> product <- "MOD13Q1"
> h = 26
> v = 4
> getT <- getTile(tileH = 26, tileV = 4)
> runGdal(job = "NDVI", product = product, begin = dates2$beginDOY, end = dates2$endDOY, extent = getT)
No collection specified, getting the newest for MOD13Q1 
########################
outProj          =  asIn 
pixelSize        =  asIn 
resamplingType   =  near 
Output Directory =  D:/NDVI_Processed//Dali 
########################
Downloading structure on 'LAADS' for: MOD13Q1.006
Downloading structure from 'LAADS'-server! Try: 1 
Downloading structure of '0' from 'LAADS'-server.                        

Error in if (FtpDayDirs[1] == FALSE) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Before this error, I spent some time on the rgdal problem, and solved it by installing OSGeo4W and specifying the rgdal library. Here is my sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MODIS_1.1.2   raster_2.6-7  mapdata_2.3.0 maps_3.3.0    rgdal_1.3-4  
[6] sp_1.3-1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18    compiler_3.5.1  later_0.7.3     nloptr_1.0.4   
 [5] bitops_1.0-6    class_7.3-14    tools_3.5.1     digest_0.6.16  
 [9] memoise_1.1.0   lattice_0.20-35 shiny_1.1.0     DBI_1.0.0      
[13] parallel_3.5.1  spData_0.2.9.3  e1071_1.7-0     withr_2.1.1    
[17] rgeos_0.3-28    devtools_1.13.6 classInt_0.2-3  mapedit_0.3.2  
[21] grid_3.5.1      sf_0.6-3        R6_2.2.2        ptw_1.9-13     
[25] XML_3.98-1.16   foreign_0.8-70  magrittr_1.5    units_0.6-0    
[29] promises_1.0.1  htmltools_0.3.6 maptools_0.9-3  mime_0.5       
[33] xtable_1.8-3    httpuv_1.4.5    RCurl_1.95-4.11
```

And, my MODISoptions

```
> MODISoptions()

STORAGE:
_______________
localArcPath : D:/NDVI/ 
outDirPath   : D:/NDVI_Processed/ 


DOWNLOAD:
_______________
MODISserverOrder : LAADS, LPDAAC 
dlmethod         : auto 
stubbornness     : high 
wait             : 0.5 
quiet            : FALSE 


PROCESSING:
_______________
GDAL           : GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19 
MRT            : Version 4.1 (March 2011) 
pixelSize      : asIn 
outProj        : asIn 
resamplingType : NN 
dataFormat     : GTiff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try this once again using **MODIS_1.1.3** (or higher) which is now available from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=MODIS)? The package received a comprehensive update, which especially addresses issues related to data download from LAADS and LP DAAC (the latter requires the specification of Earthdata login credentials). With this package version, your code runs smoothly on my machine.

```
library(MODIS)

getT = getTile(tileH = 26, tileV = 4)
tfs = runGdal(job = "NDVI", product = "MOD13Q1", begin = "2000.02.18", end = "2000.03.10", extent = getT)
tfs
# $`MOD13Q1.006`
# $`MOD13Q1.006`$`2000-02-18`
# [1] ".../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/NDVI/MOD13Q1.A2000049.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif"                     
# [2] ".../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/NDVI/MOD13Q1.A2000049.250m_16_days_EVI.tif"                      
# (etc.)       
# 
# $`MOD13Q1.006`$`2000-03-05`
# [1] ".../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/NDVI/MOD13Q1.A2000065.250m_16_days_NDVI.tif"                     
# [2] ".../MODIS_ARC/PROCES~1/NDVI/MOD13Q1.A2000065.250m_16_days_EVI.tif"                      
# (etc.)
```

Please also check out my answers to the following SO questions

- [Download MODIS/MCD19A2 AOD product with R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295080/download-modis-mcd19a2-aod-product-with-r)
- [MODIS R Connection error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283164/modis-r-connection-error)
- and [Troubleshooting downloading MODIS NDVI Data in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281625/troubleshooting-downloading-modis-ndvi-data-in-r)

which include further details that might be relevant for you (deliberately omitted here to avoid repetition).

Comment: Thanks @fdetsch very much for the answer and for updating the package. Now the codes works fairly well.